# Is this code correct for overloading comparision operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

Is the following code correct for overloading comparision operator? Are there any silly mistakes or loop holes in this peice of code? I am especially doubtful about the if loop `if (b1 == b2)` or `if (&b1 == &b2)`? Which one is correct, eventually pass by reference right, I think. What about if we allocate objects on heap, can we compare pointers?

Here is the code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base{
private:
    //static const int i=10;
    int j;
    string str;
public:
    //void display() const;
    //int read();
    bool operator==(const Base &rhs);
};

bool Base::operator ==(const Base &rhs)
{
    if((this->j == rhs.j) && (this->str == rhs.str))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Base b1, b2;
    if(&b1 == &b2) // or if(b1 == b2)
    {
        cout << "Equal\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not equal\n";
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function signature says to compiler that comparision operator could change the object value, so it can't be called on const object. So it would be better to declare it as const:

```
bool operator==(const Base &rhs) const;
```

In this code your are comparing addresses of two objects:

```
if(&b1 == &b2) // or if(b1 == b2)
{
    cout << "Equal\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "Not equal\n";
}
```

They are obviously not equal. if (b1 == b2) { ... } correct if you want check for objects equality.

> What about if we allocate objects on heap, can we compare pointers?

If a and b would be pointers you can compare pointers values as:

```
*a == *b
```

or call operator== explicitly (what is ugly):

```
a->operator==(*b)
```

It's common in c++ declare such operators as friends (but in your case it's not required). Also using of this inside of this code doesn't make readability better. I would like to see this operator as:

```
bool Base::operator == (const Base & rhs) const
{
    return j == rsh.j and str == rhs.str;
}
```

As general note, because the class is called Base probably you may be need to declare it as virtual also.

ADDED: Also in this case *j* will not initialized. The simplest way to fix it just add initializer to declaration:

```
class Base {
private:
    int j = 0;
    string str;
// ...
};
```

Comment: In either case, I am getting Not equal. If the contents are same, then the equality should return true right?

Comment: In your case your are comparing two objects what wasn't initialized. So if string by default initialized as empty, then i is initialized by garbage every time.

Comment: Yes I got your meaning, if I comment the int and string, and compare only static const, then the two objects are equal.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I have edited the answer to add example how you could init j without constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The comparison operator logic looks correct, but

1. you are missing a `const`

   ```
   bool operator==(const Base &rhs) const;
   ```

   which is the promise you make to the compiler that your operator isn't going to modify the instance over which it is invoked; without it your operator isn't usable in a comparison where the left hand side is `const`.
2. of course it is not invoked by the line

   ```
   if(&b1 == &b2)
   ```

   since here you are comparing pointers, which already have their comparison operator (that returns `true` if the two pointers point to the same instance). The correct way to actually invoke your operator is to compare the objects directly, like

   ```
   if(b1 == b2)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The code posted is comparing the memory addresses of the base objects. This if statement will always compare false between b1 and b2, unless b1 is b2.

Answer (score 1):

As per the current implementation, Make the following change
Replace `(&b1 == &b2)` with `(b1 == b2)`, and your code will work fine

`(&b1 == &b2)` => compares the address, which can never be same.
`(b1 == b2)`  => compares the contents.